# How to change out-of-focus text selection color in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, syntax, colors, find, selection

Okay, I'll bite.

I've got really pleasant code/window colors set up in Xcode. Ordinarily, my selection color is very visible.

When I am doing a project search and iterating through the results, however, the results list stays in focus and the found text remains out of focus, using a different background color. This color is extremely hard to detect, especially when the text is embedded in a larger code block and the view is shifting around as it scrolls to the results.

Here's an example:

[Left side is in focus (just normal selection), right side is out of focus (during project find)](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/9780/infocusoutoffocus.jpg)

Often it takes a few seconds to find where the heck the selected text is.

Unless I'm just missing it, Xcode seems to offer no way to change this particular selection color. Interestingly, it also doesn't seem to follow the selection color from the Appearance panel.

Does anyone know a way to change this color or force it to be more visible, short of changing my entire color scheme around?

Comment: I believe there is no way to do this except hacking like that given in @Steven's answer. I suggest report a bug in radar. I just filed one. The more people report this problem, the more likely Apple is going to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Xcode plugin:

http://github.com/tjw/XcodeSelectionColorFix

Instructions for using it are here: http://github.com/tjw/XcodeSelectionColorFix/blob/master/README.markdown

Comment: No, but Apple has fixed the bug since. It still isn't especially attractive, but it's no longer always the same color as it was in Xcode 3 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit the theme file, which might allow a different selection color. If I recall (not on my dev machine), personal themes are in 
`~/Library/Application Support/Xcode/(should be intuitive from here/can't remember)`
You can edit them in Property List Editor, if I remember right. The Xcode preferences don't expose all of the options available in the theme file.

Comment: The problem is there is not such key to set the secondary selection color for.